# What is the difference between grid.columns and grid.getColumnManager().getColumns() in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

In Ext Js `grid.columns` and `grid.getColumnManager().getColumns()` both the functions gives the list of columns available in grid. I want to know the difference between both the functions and which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

`grid.columns` is just property that contains array of `Ext.grid.column.Column` instances.

`grid.getColumnManager().getColumns()` is **private** method and somewhat getter function for the same array passed via headerCtConfig (check [`Ext.grid.ColumnManager`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/ColumnManager.html#Ext-grid-ColumnManager-method-getColumns)).

To get columns config you actually have to use **public** [`Ext.grid.Panel.getColumns()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getColumns) method, but, if you check source you'll see that it just use ColumnManager anyway:

```
getColumns: function () {
    return this.getColumnManager().getColumns();
},
```